# Why the component from ratchet is not rendering properly

Tags: html, css, ratchet-2, ratchet-bootstrap

This is my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ashoksahoo/PLN4n/).
I added CSS component from [Segmented Control](http://goratchet.com/components/#segmentedControls) and added relevant libraries, but doesn't work as intended, like in the web site:

```
<div class="segmented-control">
... Control components...
</div>
<div class="card">
... control content
 </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are going to need to check out the [Getting Started](http://goratchet.com/getting-started/) page, and read through it.

The segments don't work in the jsFiddle because they only responde to "touch" events (like on a mobile device) and not "click" events (like on a PC).

From the [GitHub - Ratchet](https://github.com/twbs/ratchet) documentation.

> Ratchet is designed to respond to touch events from a mobile device.
>   In order to use mouse click events (for desktop browsing and testing),
>   you have a few options: Enable touch event emulation in Chrome (found
>   in the overrides tab in the web inspector preferences) Use a
>   JavaScript library like fingerblast.js to emulate touch events
>   (ideally only loaded from desktop devices)

Also, some of the styles are missing for a few reasons.

- The component examples have extra styling that is not in the framework.
- Your jsFiddle is missing a `<div class="content">` wrapper.
- [This jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PLN4n/1/) is closer, but still won't fully work because of the touch event issue from above, but at least it points you in the right direction.

Comment: I was wondering how it works in my phonegap app, but I cant test it properly locally, works as intended with chrome's mobile emulation mode but there are some rendering issues.